# problems with path of msp430 gcc

Tags: bash, gcc, paths

Hi everyone I'm trying to modify the path to open `msp430-gcc`

When I use whereis `msp430-gcc` :

> msp430-gcc: /usr/bin/msp430-gcc /usr/bin/X11/msp430-gcc
>   /opt/msp430-47/bin/msp430-gcc

And what I want is that the firs option was `/opt/msp430-47/bin/msp430-gcc`

In my `~/.bashrc` file my path is `PATH=~/opt/msp430-47/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

I've tried to cp th msp430-gcc doc to the `/usr/bin`. It changes me the version but then I can't compile anything because the files are in other dir.. tha is `/opt/msp430-47`.

How can I make to put all in the correct path ?

Comment: `~/opt` would be a directory called `opt` *in your home directory*: if you want the toplevel system directory `/opt` then omit the `~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your preferred path **first**:

   ```
   PATH=/opt/msp430-47/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Check it

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```
2. Fix permissions

   ```
   sudo find /opt/msp430-47 -type d -exec chmod +rx "{}" \;
   sudo chmod -R +rx /opt/msp430-47/bin
   ```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: PATH=/opt/msp430-47/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games 

even in /etc/sudoers the secure path is 

secure_path="/opt/msp430-47/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Comment: @EfremBlazquez, Path setup now ok. Possible you have a permissions problem. Updated my answer

Comment: ohhhh I made the Fix permission step... and it works !! 

Thanks !! can you explain me why if I was working like  SU i had problems with permissions.. ???

Comment: @EfremBlazquez , With superuser you can read folder/files  but you can't execute any command from that bin if they don't have execution bit set.

Comment: OK.. now i have a new problem.. when i try to compile some program using msp430 - gcc it tells me 


msp430-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj_z1/rimeaddr.o] Error 1

it is for something similar??

Comment: @EfremBlazquez, Would you accept this as this what work for you. See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers . You look new here

Comment: @EfremBlazquez, That seems a different problem could you write new question and post your code too.